# the ln of a variable

Tags: logarithms

I have the equation $2t-5.682511886=-2*\ln(3t)+\ln(30t)$

I need to solve this equation to find t but I am unable to do that because of the natural logs

So my question is how do you deal with something like $\ln(6t^2)$ (as an example).

Comment: Natural Logs work just the same way as what you do with $\log_{10}$. So, for your question, $\ln \left( 6t^2 \right) = \ln \left( 6 \right) + 2 \ln \left( t \right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation $$2t-a=-2*\log(3t)+\log(30t)=-2\log(3)-2\log(t)+\log(30)+\log(t)$$ that is to say
$$2t+\log(t)=b\qquad \text{with} \qquad b=a-2\log(3)+\log(30)$$

The solution for $t$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and write
$$t=\frac{1}{2} W\left(2 e^b\right)$$

Now, using the value of $a$, $b=6.886484690$ and $t=2.909288133$.

If you cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods will solve the problem.